# different hover effect with raphael js

Tags: jquery, hover, raphael

i'm building an interactive map with raphael plugin js.
http://jsfiddle.net/6CvXF/6

i've set up different loop to wrap some path for color. now, how can i do different hover color for this different loops?

thanks for your suggestion

two example of the loops:

```
//Abbigliamento
var rosa = {};
rosa["2"] = map.path("M 361.414,300.778 354.578,307.089 354.433,362.433 367.838,362.433 367.838,373.704     430.308,373.704 430.308,300.778    z");
rosa["4"] = map.path("M 326.896,373.593 326.896,363.609 347.391,363.609 347.391,306.804 341.781,301.02 264.493,301.02     264.493,337.675 269.733,342.916 269.64,373.593    z");
rosa["5"] = map.path("M240.633,300.778c0-0.394-41.99-0.197-63.07-0.074v11.323H160.7l0.036,61.726h75.203l-0.214-29.676    l4.909-5.434C240.633,338.643,240.633,301.303,240.633,300.778z");

for(var civico in rosa) {
    rosa[civico].attr(style);
}

//Cultura
var arancio = {};
arancio["3"] = map.path("M 354.578,307.089 361.181,300.544 373.575,300.544 373.575,309.04            354.578,309.039    z");
arancio["7"] = map.path("M 113.015,300.954 113.015,365.639 129.493,365.639 129.636,373.527 129.493,365.639     134.356,365.541 134.467,353.893 128.441,300.602    z");
arancio["8"] = map.path("M 93.731,300.954 113.015,300.954 113.015,365.765 129.493,365.765 129.493,373.668 93.978,373.668        z");
arancio["9"] = map.rect(445.229, 260.62, 39, 19);
arancio["10"] = map.rect(412.147, 260.62, 39, 19);

for(var civico in arancio) {
   arancio[civico].attr(style);
}
```

Comment: Its not clear really what bit you are having a problem with. Just add something like element.hover( function() { this.attr( myStyleObject ) }); You probably want to include the hoverout part as well. http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.hover  You could have an array of different styles, or just apply them after each map.path() element.

Comment: hi Ian, yes i would like to hove different color for each array but i still couldn't find a working solution

Answer (score 0):

You can just set up your styles in an array, and then set your hover style function...

```
var styles = [];
styles[2] = { fill: "red", stroke: "blue" };
styles[3] = { fill: "red", stroke: "blue" };
styles[4] = { fill: "blue", stroke: "red" };
styles[5] = { fill: "yellow", stroke: "green" };
styles[7] = { fill: "yellow", stroke: "green" };

function myStyleFunc( which ) {
    this.attr( styles[ which ] ); 
}
```

and later (or earlier outside the loop when you setup the path)

```
for(var civico in rosa) {
    rosa[civico].attr(style).hover( myStyleFunc.bind(rosa[civico], civico)        );
}
```

fiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6CvXF/12/)

Comment: thanks for your effort but when i will work with map with a lot of spaces (what i called civico with numbers) i have to set up one by one. i would like that the color works with the var rosa if it's possible, so i don't care how much place i'll add. hope i was clear about this point

Comment: No idea what you mean, I suspect its a language thing if you can clarify it.

Comment: yes probably i can't explain it better. btw i resolved applying an id to each array and i style with css. thanks anyway